# Need help in python code for Binance future order

Tags: python-3.x, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

I want to create a function in python that can place the future order with target and stop loss. Once the target or stop loss hit, It should close the order. I have tried to create a function but it did not work

```
def place_future_order(symbol,side,quantity,target,sl):
    order1=binance_client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type="MARKET", quantity=quantity)
    print(order1)
    while True:
        response = binance_client.get_open_orders()
        if(response==[]):
            print("ORDER FILED")
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    order2=binance_client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type="TAKE_PROFIT_MARKET", quantity=quantity, stopPrice=target)
    print(order2)
    order3=binance_client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type="STOP_MARKET", quantity=quantity, stopPrice=sl)
    print(order3)
```

Comment: can you explain the "but it did not work" part please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.